# Trying to install geoip extension for php, Getting error pecl5.6 command not found

Tags: php, linux

I am installing GeoIP extension for PHP on Ubuntu. I am getting below error.

```
sudo pecl5.6-sp install geoip
sudo: pecl5.6-sp: command not found
```

Comment: Have you tried just `pecl install geoip`?

Comment: Yes, after that i got a file. and after enabling this in .ini noting is happening